# WSO2 Api Manager disable stats for a API

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Is it possible to disable just one API from sending stats to BAM?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can remove this line from relevant synapse file of the API which is in `repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/api/`

```
<handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtUsageHandler"/>
```

Please note that your change will be reverted if you update the API from publisher UI.